# How to have a pushpin (MapIcon) without the black line and offset

Tags: xaml, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm using a XAML-MapControl in a UWP-project.

When you create a MapIcon, the image is floating a fixed offset above the desired location on the map, instead of directly on the map, with a black line connecting the icon with the map, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I can't find a way to remove this line, or reduce its size.

And none of the other MapElement-types seem to do what I want, I want the exact behavior of the MapIcon, but without this line.

Is there a way to do that?

**Edit**:
Here's how I create the MapIcons:

```
var icon = new MapIcon
{
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
    Image = image,
    Visible = true,
};
MapControl.MapElements.Add(icon);
```

**Edit2**:

I tried to set the stylysheet, but it does not work for me, probably because it's only supported in a version newer than the one I target:

```
MapControl.StyleSheet = MapStyleSheet.ParseFromJson("{ \"version\": \"1.*\", \"settings\": { }, \"elements\": { \"userPoint\": { \"stemAnchorRadiusScale\": 0, \"stemHeightScale\": 0 }}}");
```

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to create these

Comment: I don't see how that will help, but ok

Comment: Have you tried to set a different `Altitude` of the `MapIcon`'s `Location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the stemAnchorRadiusScale and stemHeightScale properties of userPoint to 0 in the map style sheet. See this topic for how to work with style sheets:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/elements-of-map-style-sheet.
For example:

```js
{
    "version": "1.*",
    "settings": {
    },
    "elements": {
        "userPoint": {
            "stemAnchorRadiusScale": 0,
            "stemHeightScale": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't work. Did I do something wrong? I added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I noticed these properties are only supported from version 1713, and apparently we target 1629, so I guess that explains why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's correct - these properties will only work on Windows builds 1713 or later. You can set them on earlier builds, but they won't have any effect. You might look into the MapBillboard as an alternative. While the behavior is slightly different than MapIcon, it won't have a stem or anchor